# How do I replace the a specific first character of lines with something else in multiple .txt files? (Python)

Tags: python, file, io

So basically I have .txt files in this sort of form

```
0 45 56 67 89
1 45 56 33 21
```

Some .txt files might also be blank. Some may contain one or more lines. Now I want to replace all the 1 in the first character of lines to 0. Everything else remains same. So the above .txt example should look like

```
0 45 56 67 89
0 45 56 33 21
```

I tried two ways One way was :

```
import glob
import os
source="path of my folder/"
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(source, '*.txt')):
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), "r+") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(source, '*.txt')):
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), "w+") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if line[0]=='1':
                line[0].replace('1','0')
```

But this just removes all lines, regardless of whether it starts with 0 or 1

I have tried this:

```
source="path/ of my folder which has the files/"
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(source):
    for f in filenames:
        this_file = open(os.path.join(source, f), "r")
        this_files_data = this_file.readlines()
        this_file.close()
# rewrite the file with all line except the one you don't want
        this_file = open(os.path.join(source, f), "w")
        for line in this_files_data:
            if line[0] in "1":
                line[0].replace("0","1")
                this_file.write(line)
        this_file.close()
```

But this just removes all lines starting with 0 and keeps the ones with 1.

Comment: You're replacing the `line` variable each time through the first loop. When you start the second loop it contains the lines from the last file.

Comment: Do your files have spaces at the beginning of each line like you show?

Comment: You're also never writing anything in the first script.

Comment: @Barmar no spaces in beginning a line just starts with 0 or 1

Comment: @Barmar what am I doing wrong in the second script?

Comment: The second script only writes the lines that were updated.

Comment: I also don't understand why you didn't use `with`, since you obviously know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use just one loop. Read each file, make the changes you want, then rewrite the file.

You can use a regular expression to replace `1` at the start of each line.

```
import re
import glob
import os

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(source, '*.txt')):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        contents = f.read()
    contents = re.sub(r'^1', '0', contents, flags = re.MULTILINE)
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(contents)
```

You shouldn't use `os.path.join(getcwd(), filename)`. The files are in the `source` directory, not the current directory, and `glob.glob()` returns those pathnames.